# DataStore not running

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a gamepass script where when you join you will be told to buy a gamepass. but When you join the game the Gamepass promt wont show up. and the output does not give me a error

```lua
local marketplaceservice = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local gamepassid = 11585012233

local function PromtPurchase()
    local players = game.Players.LocalPlayer
    local haspass = false
    local success, message = pcall(function()
        local hasspass = 
    marketplaceservice:PromptGamePassPurchase(players.UserId,gamepassid)
        if haspass == true then
            print("Player has pass")
            marketplaceservice:PromptGamePassPurchase(players, gamepassid)

        else
            marketplaceservice:PromptGamePassPurchase(players, gamepassid)
        end
    end)


    wait(1)
    promtPurchase()
```

Comment: Heyo, when you ask a question here, it is not enough to say that something doesn't work. You need to explain what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening. Are there any error messages in the Output? Please edit your question to include more information and be specific about what you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

```
local hasspass = marketplaceservice:PromptGamePassPurchase(players.UserId,gamepassid)
```

This is a prompting function, so it'll just prompt every time, you want to be using

```
local hasspass = marketplaceservice:UserOwnsGamePassAsync(players.UserId, gamepassid)
```